# Let B(0,r) denote ball of radius r. Thus B(0, 1/2) is contained in B(0,1). Let T be a linear map, does it follow that T(B1/2) is contained in T(B1)?

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading Folland's real analysis on the proof of "open mapping theorem".
If y belongs to the closure of T(B1/2), doesn't it follow automatically that y belongs to T(B1)?

Comment: Where are we, in a metric space, $\mathbb R^n,$ a Banach space ...?

Comment: _Banach space_ 'code'